# How to add menu items to Electron Menu from list of serial ports

Tags: menu, electron

In my electron app, I am using SerialPort to interface with Arduino devices. I want to list the ports available (plugged in arduinos) in the Electron menu. 
I now do not know how I can send the data from my `renderer.js` file to my main process and then build the menu with all items added there, before my app loads.

I'm using this template to build my menu and the following script to fetch all serial ports:

```js
const template = [
    {
        label: 'Edit',
        submenu: [
            { role: 'undo' },
            { role: 'redo' }
        ]
    },
    {
        label: 'Ports',
        submenu: [
            { 
                label: 'select port',
                submenu: [
                    { label: 'Port1' },
                    { label: 'Port2' },
                    { label: 'Port3' }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    { label: 'Help' }
]
```

```js
// renderer.js
const serialport = require('serialport')
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

get_ports = function () {
    console.log('clicked')
    serialport.list((err, ports) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return
        } else {
            console.log(ports)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send the ports the `serialport.list ()` function provides via IPC to your main process, where you put them to the template and then set this as your application's menu.

For example, the renderer process' file:

```js
const serialport = require ("serialport");
const { ipcRenderer } = require ("electron");

get_ports = function () {
    console.log ('clicked');
    serialport.list ((err, ports) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log (err);
            return;
        } else {
            ipcRenderer.send ("serialports", ports);
        }
    })
}
```

And then inside your main process' file:

```js
// `template' as in your question
const { ipcMain, Menu } = require ("electron");

ipcMain.on ("serialports", (event, data) => {
    var portsSubmenu = [];

    for (port in data) {
        portsSubmenu.push ({ label: port.comName });
    }

    template[1].submenu[0].submenu = portsSubmenu;
    Menu.setApplicationMenu (Menu.buildFromTemplate (template));
});
```

The indices of the submenu you want to modify (here `template[1].submenu[0]`) change, if you put new items before your `"Ports"` item.

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked great! I was at first confused as to why you said to build the menu inside the ipcMain call but then realized it is getting built before the message is sent from the renderer. Cheers!